# How to remove a callback registered with a pub/sub datastore?

Tags: javascript

See the following simple pub/sub-type dataStore which I have implemented:

```
class DataStore {
    constructor() {
        this.store = {};
        this.callbacks = {};
    }

    getState(key) {
        return this.store[key];
    }

    setState(key, value) {
        this.store[key] = value;
        this.callbacks[key].forEach( callback => {
            callback(this.store[key]);
        });
    }

    onChange(key, callback) {
        this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks.key || [];
        this.callbacks[key].push(callback);
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to implement a `removeCallback` method for this class, and I am not really getting anywhere. I can call `filter` on the `callbacks` and use `!==` to find the exact function and remove it, i.e.:

```
removeCallback(key, callback) {
    this.callbacks[key].filter( cb => cb !== callback );
}
```

--but that approach is dependent on having the callback saved, which I wouldn't. See below:

```
store.onChange('someValue', val => { /* do something with val */ });
store.removeCallback('someValue', ???);
```

Since the function passed to `onChange` was effectively anonymous, how can I identify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller of `removeCallback` *needs* to have something that uniquely identifies the callback. The easiest way would be to store the callback in a variable first:

```
const cb = val => { /* do something with val */ };
store.onChange('someValue', cb);
store.removeCallback('someValue', cb);
```

Also note that `.filter` does not mutate the existing array - you'd need to assign the result of `.filter` to `this.callbacks[key]`:

```
removeCallback(key, callback) {
  this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks[key].filter( cb => cb !== callback );
}
```

You also probably want to change

```
this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks.key || [];
```

to

```
this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks[key] || [];
                                    ^^^^^
```

Or, you might use a `Set` instead, removing the need for `.filter` and iteration:

```
onChange(key, callback) {
  this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks[key] || new Set();
  this.callbacks[key].add(callback);
}
removeCallback(key, callback) {
  this.callbacks[key].delete(callback);
}
```

If you wanted to be slightly terser, you could have `onChange` return the passed callback:

```
const cb = store.onChange('someValue', (val) => { ... });
```

with

```
onChange(key, callback) {
  this.callbacks[key] = this.callbacks[key] || new Set();
  this.callbacks[key].add(callback);
  return callback;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but what if the callback-creating code is called twice, and then you want to remove the first one? Or, to be clearer and jump to the true core of that question, what if the callback-creating code is called N times, and then you want to remove the N-Kth one?

Comment: So `onChange` is called with the same callback multiple times? That's kind of odd, do you *want* the callback to run twice when triggered in that situation? (note that similar mechanisms, like `addEventListener`, will *ignore* duplicate added handlers - it's like a `Set` - you might consider using that sort of functionality too)

Comment: In a situation where the nature of the attached callback is run-time user-choice dependent, then it would not be a duplicate.

Comment: If the passed callback is not the same, then there shouldn't be an issue - just save the callbacks in variables and call `removeCallback` with those variables when you want to remove them. (feel free to use an object or array of such callbacks for better organization, maybe connected to the class if you want)